Estne aliquod erratum grammaticum hic?
"Puto, carissime lector, scientiae mortem te angere. Quia fidem tuam pecunia commutavis, et nemo tibi veniam dare idcirco potest. Sic a beata vita longe es, et mors tua imminet tenebrosorum peccatorum causa."

In periodo prima nullum video peccatum contra grammaticam, sed miror verbum «scientia» nonne in accusativo casu scribendum fuisse, «mors» vicissim in genetivo?
In periodo secunda commutavisti scribendum fuit.
Quod in tertia periodo scripsisti «peccatorum causa», nota bene ablativum «causa» cum genetivo saepissime finem actionum significare, vel quam aliquo facto augere volumus rem.
Remotis quaestionibus grammaticis, tota oratio mihi obscura vel etiam abstrusa videtur, et plane eam non intellego.

Nunc mea crassa peccata percipio; emendare enim ea errata volo. Potesne tu corrigere meas periodos iterum, si magis errata invenias? Correctionem tibi scribam, si accipias id quod propono.

"Puto, carissime lector, mortis scientiam te angere. Quia fidem tuam pecunia commutavisti, et nemo tibi veniam dare potest. Longe ergo a beata vita es, et mors tua imminet tenebrosis peccatis"

Ut bene intellegas, anglica lingua nunc utor: "I think, dear reader, that the consciousness of death annoys you; because you exchanged your loyalt by money, and because of this no one can forgive you. Thus, you are far from the happy life, and your death is coming by your gloomy sins." Putas me de Latino in Anglicam Linguam bene convertisse?
